# I need to extract from a string some values situated between brackets using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have this string and I need to extract values after $env and situated between brackets.

```
$env(test_$env(test1_$env(test2))) $env(test3)
```

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
/\s*env\(([^)]+)\)/g
```

I expect the following output in an array:

```
test_$env(test1_$env(test2))
test1_$env(test2)
test2
test3
```

Comment: Try `/(?=env(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\)))/g`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7p13kJ/2). The values are in Group 2. Do you mean `perl` or `pcre`?

Comment: @WiktorStribizew that's for sure what I want to extract, the values from group2. Is there anyway to extract only values from group2? I need without the brackets. But anyway, that's magic pff..  and for your question, I mean Perl.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/cxchvm

Comment: Thank you very much! You are awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/(?=env(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\)))/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7p13kJ/2).

**Details**

- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead to allow overlapping matches

  - `env` - a literal `env` text
  - `(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))` - Group 1, necessary to recurse the parenthesized substrings inside `env(...)`, matching

    - `\(` - a `(` char
    - `((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)` - Group 2 (to hold the value to extract): 0 or more sequences (`*`) of 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` (`[^()]++`) or the whole Group 1 pattern (`(?1)`)
    - `\)` - a `)`
- `)` - end of the lookahead

See the [online code demo](https://ideone.com/cxchvm):

```
$string = '$env(test_$env(test1_$env(test2))) $env(test3)';
while($string =~ /(?=env(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\)))/g) {
    print "$2\n";
}
```